# Вытащить пароли с PHPdesigner и FTP Filezilla?

Tags: php

Всем привет. Часто кто юзает эти программы. ПРоблема в том что есть острая необходимость переустановки ОС. Как можно сохранить все проекты и доступы по FTP в PhpDesigner и FileZilla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Точно не знаю, стиллер для PhpDesigner не писал, но говорят настроки его тут: `C:\Users\[UserName]\Application Data\phpDesigner`. Сохрани всю папку и перенеси, должно сработать.
У Filezilla - `C:\Users\[UserName]\AppData\Roaming\FileZilla\sitemanager.xml`, обычным блокнотом открыть можно, пароль в открытом виде (порицаю вас, разработчики :)).

Comment: Хотя, с другой стороны, просмотр паролей в Filezilla не раз помогал. А так да, плохо это.

Comment: @maotm, Угу, только пароли храни в защищённом хранилище или напиши обёртку, которая будет перехватывать обращения к файлу и если процесс легальный, то давать возможность оперировать (реализовывал подобную вещь для контроля правки реестра).  
НО НИКОГДА НЕ ХРАНИ ПАРОЛИ ОТКРЫТЫМИ!

Comment: Док спасибо! Как обычно выручил!

Comment: @duddeniska, Всегда пожалуйста :)